# What is the best Deep Learning Library in R?

Tags: r, neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I am looking for a complete deep learning library in R. I am trying to find one or more libraries to implement:

- Recurrent NN
- Deep Belief NN
- Convolutional NN

I have tried multiple libraries such as deepnet,darch,RcppDL but none of them seem to do the thing right. The most crucial for me is to be well documented,because I have tried to rerun the examples of the above libraries with my data, but either they crash or they predict a constant value for all test examples.

Comment: R is probably not the right language for deep learning. AFAIK most of the big libraries use python as a scripting language.

Comment: I have understand it by now, but the goal is to use R Shiny Server, so it is a must use.

Comment: I am looking at RcppDL at the moment and I have to agree that the documnentation is not very complete. I will contact the package developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try h2o, [more information here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3200/index.html)

Comment: I have tried it but it seems a little bit confusing. Anything else?

Comment: After some research I have foaund out tha h2o implements "Deep Belief NN" and there isn't a library in R for Convolutional NN, for the time being.